# Error message from SurveyMonkey API

Tags: surveymonkey

We are currently getting an error back from the API saying "*Error communicating with endpoint System.Net.WebException: Problem querying the Survey Monkey API, error code 5: Server busy, please try again*"

Can you please check if everything is ok?

This error results when using "send_flow" and has been working for months with last successful call on 11. feb. 2015.

Thanks.

Comment: I would contact their support, api-support@surveymonkey.com.  Sounds like an internal error on their side, there may be something wrong with your account.

Comment: Hi @Rune - is this still an issue?  We're not seeing any errors at this time for that API method.  It may have been a temporary outage during a release...

Comment: Hi @RyanDugan, Yes we still get the same error. I created new keys, and before I entered the correct access token, it gave another error, so the service does seem to inpterpret requests. However, bringing in a new token (same setup as earlier), it gives the original error as described initially. Is there any logging that can be checked or anything else I can provide you for this?

The https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api_console does work with my access token, so like you say, that seems to work. It's quite strange.

Comment: Also, logging in to developer.surveymonkey.com I saw to instances of our app, so I deleted one and recreated a key, then access token for the single app I left after deleted the duplicate.

Comment: When you created the access token in the API console, did you just click "Get Access Token" or did you choose "custom application" first and then enter your API key, client ID and client secret before clicking "Get Access Token"? If you just clicked the button without entering your API key etc, the access token that is generated is for the API console's developer account and won't work with your application.